# Please help me with grep regex grouping

Tags: regex, grep

I want to clearify some outputs from `grep` for tmux using.

Here is a log:

```
Nov 07 14:51:50 SA0888 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0:       VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_ADDR   0x001F9122
Nov 07 14:51:50 SA0888 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0:       VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS 0x0A084002
Nov 07 14:51:50 SA0888 kernel: amdgpu 0000:02:00.0:       VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_ADDR   0x001F9121
Nov 07 14:51:50 SA0888 kernel: amdgpu 0000:02:00.0:       VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS 0x0A084002
Nov 07 14:51:50 SA0888 kernel: amdgpu 0000:02:00.0:       VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS 0x0A084002
```

I want to get only date and pci address for FAULT_ADDR string:

```
Nov 07 14:51:50 03:00.0
Nov 07 14:51:50 02:00.0
```

Or in perfect way:

```
Nov 07 14:51:50 ==> 03:00.0
Nov 07 14:51:50 ==> 02:00.0
```

I've made this:

```
grep -Po '([A-Za-z]{3} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})|(?<=amdgpu 0000:).*?(?=:   VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_ADDR)' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ PCI /g' | sed 's/$/\n/'
```

but now all results goes in one string, not in row.

I am stuck with grep match, because any group match grep outputs as a new string.
Also i didnt understand, how to exclude date capturing from string that doesnt contains FAULT_ADDR.

Comment: sorry, my fault, log past was incorrect, just updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an awk solution like

```
awk '/FAULT_ADDR/{s=index($7,":"); $7=substr($7,s+1,length($7)-s-1); print $1" "$2" "$3" => "$7}' file > outfile
```

**Details**

- `/FAULT_ADDR/` - find a line that contains `FAULT_ADDR`
- `{s=index($7,":"); $7=substr($7,s+1,length($7)-s-1); print $1" "$2" "$3" => "$7}` - set `s` to the start index of the first `:`, then set the seventh field to a substring between the first `:` and the last but one char, and then concatenate Field 1, Field 2, Field 3, " => " and Field 7 and print the value.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/3rWlvF):

```
s="Nov 07 14:51:50 SA0888 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0:       VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_ADDR   0x001F9122
Nov 07 14:51:50 SA0888 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0:       VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS 0x0A084002
Nov 07 14:51:50 SA0888 kernel: amdgpu 0000:02:00.0:       VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_ADDR   0x001F9121
Nov 07 14:51:50 SA0888 kernel: amdgpu 0000:02:00.0:       VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS 0x0A084002
Nov 07 14:51:50 SA0888 kernel: amdgpu 0000:02:00.0:       VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS 0x0A084002"

awk '/FAULT_ADDR/{s=index($7,":"); $7=substr($7,s+1,length($7)-s-1); print $1" "$2" "$3" => "$7}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
Nov 07 14:51:50 => 03:00.0
Nov 07 14:51:50 => 02:00.0
```

A `sed` solution if you like `sed` more:

```
sed -n -E '/FAULT_ADDR/{s/^([[:alpha:]]+ +[0-9]+ +[0-9:]+).*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]):.*/\1 ==> \2/p}' file > outfile
```

See [the online demo](https://ideone.com/h05jz6)

Here,

- `-E` - enable POSIX ERE regex syntax
- `-n` - suppress line output
- `/FAULT_ADDR/` - finds a line having `FAULT_ADDR` and only if found the replacement is tried:
- `^` - start of  string
- `([[:alpha:]]+ +[0-9]+ +[0-9:]+)` - Group 1: 1+ letters, 1+ spaces, 1+ digits, 1+ spaces, 1+ digits/colons
- `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9])` - Group 2: 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits, `.` and a digit
- `:.*` - `:` and the rest of the string
- `/\1 ==> \2/p}` - replace with Group 1, `==>`, Group 2 and print the result of replacement.

Comment: echo 'Nov 07 14:51:50 SA0888 kernel: amdgpu 0000:02:00.0:   VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_ADDR   0x001F9121' | awk '/FAULT_ADDR/{print f} {s=index($7,":"); $7=substr($7,s+1,length($7)-s-1); f=$1" "$2" "$3" => "$7}'
also nothing. what i do wrong?

Comment: this solution works like a charm! thank you!
`Nov 08 16:31:33 => 06:00.0
Nov 08 16:31:33 => 06:00.0
Nov 08 16:31:33 => 06:00.0
Nov 08 16:31:49 => 06:00.0
Nov 08 16:31:54 => 06:00.0
Nov 08 16:32:22 => 06:00.0
Nov 08 16:32:22 => 06:00.0
Nov 08 16:32:27 => 06:00.0`

Comment: @navy Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) as you are entitled to the upvoting privilege after reaching 15 rep points. Note you may upvote all the answers that turned out helpful.